# Devops Yaml dynamic stage names

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm following the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-template?view=azure-pipelines) of passing in a name to a stages template and then using that name as a var for a stage name, but it just appears to be blank everytime.

Am I missing something?

I've tried using `$(environment.uat)$(region.uk)` - but that comes through as `stage_$(environment.uat)$(region.uk)Deploy`

[image]

`Caller`

```
  - template: "yaml-templates/stages-terraform-apply-deploy.yaml/@terraform-modules"
parameters:
  name: ${{variables.environment.uat}}${{variables.region.uk}}Deploy
  ...omited...
```

`Template`

```
parameters:
  backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: null
  azureSubscription: null
  workingDirectory: ci/terraform
  varsFile: null
  tfEnvironment: null
  region: null
  appName: null
  packagePath: null
  name: ""
  dependsOn: null

stages:
  - stage: stage_${{ parameters.name}}Deploy
   
    jobs:
      - deployment: Terraform
        displayName: Azure ${{parameters.tfEnvironment}} ${{parameters.region}}
        environment: ${{parameters.tfEnvironment}}
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - download: current
                  artifact: Package

                - checkout: terraform-modules
                - checkout: self

                - template: "terraform-plan-apply.yaml/@terraform-modules"
                  parameters:
                    workingDirectory: ${{parameters.workingDirectory}}
                    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription}}
                    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: ${{parameters.backendAzureRmStorageAccountName}}
                environment: ${{parameters.tfEnvironment}}
                varsFile: ${{parameters.varsFile}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use macro variables `$(my.var.name)` notation, and using dot notation for my `${{variables.var.name}}` - switching to $${{variables.my_var_name}}` made them resolve.

Answer (score 2):

From your Template, no parameter named "stageName" is defined.

```
parameters:
  backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: null
  azureSubscription: null
  workingDirectory: ci/terraform
  varsFile: null
  tfEnvironment: null
  region: null
  appName: null
  packagePath: null
  name: ""
  dependsOn: null
```

If you are using this Template multiple times in your pipeline, then the below will be recognized as "stage_Deploy" since no value for ${{ parameters.stageName }}

```
  - stage: stage_${{ parameters.stageName }}Deploy
```

> "The Stage name stage_Deploy appears more than once"

Your error message also proves this. You need to define a parameter named "stageName" in your Template.

Modify as below:

Caller:

```
  - template: "yaml-templates/stages-terraform-apply-deploy.yaml/@terraform-modules"
parameters:
  stageName: devuk
  ...omited...
```

Template:

```
parameters:
  backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: null
  azureSubscription: null
  workingDirectory: ci/terraform
  varsFile: null
  tfEnvironment: null
  region: null
  appName: null
  packagePath: null
  stageName: ""
  dependsOn: null
```

Comment: Oh heck - clearly been stuck on this issue too long! That wasn't even my actual issue! I'll edit